# use array from windows form to web service

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services

Im trying to use windows form with web service and facing this issue :
Cannot convert int[] to array of int. 
in my windows form when tring to pass int[] to webservice and my code as bellow :
Web Service code:

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{    
    [WebMethod]
    public int plus(int [] x)
    {
        int y=x[0] + x[1];
        return y;
    }
}
```

and windows form code is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] x = new int [2];
            x[0] = 1;
            ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient c = new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient();                
            c.plus(x);
        }
```

sure I added ServiceReference before and its OK but the error in "c.plus(x)" line : 
Cannot convert int[] to array of int.
I have tried to add c.plus(x.ToList()); and same error.
I have tried to configure service reference and change collection type to generic.list and also same error.
any suggestion ?

Comment: Why are you creating an old (and not very compatible) ASMX service instead of a WCF service?

Comment: You created an old (pre-2008) ASMX service but you used the `Service Reference` button to create your proxy, which works with WS-I compatible services. WSDL and XSDs were very different back then.  You need to use the `Add Web Reference` button to add an old-style proxy. A better option though is to create a WCF service. Users of your service will *not* be amused if they have to deal with an incompatible service

Comment: Another consideration is that ASMX services are in maintenance mode - no new features, bugs are fixed infrequently and often only released during major .NET upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a web reference instead of service reference , May the article will help you

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-use-a-web-service-in-windows-form-application1

Comment: The article is simply wrong - in .NET you use WCF to create web services, not the ancient ASMX services. You don't explain *why* the OP should use a Web reference either - because he built an ASMX service instead of a WCF service. The OP would have the same problem working with *any* WS-I compatible web service

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Its not wrong, Its a way if required,right?

Comment: No, it's 100% wrong. If you want to create a web service, you use WCF. *NOT* ASMX. If you want to call a web service you use `Service Reference`, *NOT* `Add Web Reference`. That's because ASMX services and proxies don't understand the *interoperability* standards created in the last decade.

Comment: Besides, the article is a modified copy of the old MSDN articles. The article that explains how to create the service contains *verbatim* copies [of entire paragraphs from the 2003 articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx). A common occurence with `c-sharpcorner` I could say.

Comment: Oh, Yah Okey. WCF is a best option.

Comment: It's not exactly an option, it's a requirement. Unless you decide to use third-party libraries like ServiceStack. Otherwise people won't be able to *call* your service at all

Comment: Yah, I understood, Thanks,